# Max rep in a day

Tags: discussion, questions, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

I get the badge [Mortarboard badge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3850595/jordi-castilla?tab=badges) today **¡yipie! :)**, but actually I have `+197` rep because a couple of downvotes, one [sent here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30434001/3850595) (flagged and expecting answer to be deleted) and another [received here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30436011/3850595) (which I think is unfair so I want to keep the answer to help the user):

[image]

**If someone upvotes one of my questions or answers**

- Will I receive `+3` rep ?
- Will I receive `+5` or `+10`?
- Will I don't receive any rep changes?

Comment: I see you have 5 accepted answers, you can reach 275.

Comment: @MarounMaroun The poster is not asking about getting **more** than 200. He is asking why he got the badge even though he had **less** than 200 rep on the day. At least that's how I understand the question.

Comment: @retokorafi see the questions in bullets.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Yeah, looks like there are more questions at the bottom. I focused on the first paragraph and screen shot.

Comment: @Qwertiy I didn't changed authors intention, just improved the code, also I want to give rep to answerer, so, I modified the answer. That's all... please remove previous non-related-to-this-question comments. :)